# Is there a way to access bluetooth or jacked headphone's functionalities and trigger them via ios swift code

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, core-bluetooth

I am trying to connect a wired/jacked headphone and also Bluetooth headphone with my app. The headphones has noise cancellation in it. I want a way to be able to toggle active noise cancellation on/off via my app in ios swift.

I have experience in the past connecting bluetooth Blood Pressure Device to fetch the readings. But I am trying to figure out a way to access headphones.

Note: I am not looking for a way to get the events like `remoteControlReceived` where any button clicked in headphone triggers in the code.
I am not looking for this:

```
override func remoteControlReceived(with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (event?.type == UIEventType.remoteControl) {
        if event?.subtype == UIEventSubtype.remoteControlTogglePlayPause {
            //execute the code ...
        }
    }
}
```

but the other way around.
Thank you

Comment: There is no standard for controlling settings like that. Each manufacturer would have their own characteristics.  You would need to reverse engineer each different device's protocols

Comment: Totally agreed. Different products, and even different versions of products, even by the same manufacturer may control ANC differently. Across products that I work on there's at least three radically different transport protocols. And not all products even think of ANC in the same way. Some of the products I work on have a toggle, others use a multi-value mode setting, and others treat it as a gain setting like volume. Sorry for the bad news, but this is a very proprietary and custom space.